# iText certificate verification

Tags: itext, digital-signature

I'm following the iText certificate verification example (it's the 3rd example found here: https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-7/digital-signatures-chapter-5).

I don't quite get the following piece of code (I'm using iTextsharp with C#, but code for java is similar):

```
PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = base.VerifySignature(fields, name);
X509Certificate[] certs = pkcs7.SignCertificateChain;
DateTime cal = pkcs7.SignDate;
Object[] errors = CertificateVerification.VerifyCertificates(certs, certificates, null, cal);
```

`certificates` is the list used to verify `certs` (`certificates` are trusted certificates). In the example, it's created from the next files:

```
public const String ADOBE = "../../../../resources/adobeRootCA.cer";
public const String CACERT = "../../../../resources/CACertSigningAuthority.crt";
public const String BRUNO = "../../../../resources/bruno.crt";
```

I'm not sure where should I get those files from when trying to implement this myself.
I'm thinking of verifying the signatures certificates against trusted certificates in Windows store, but since I don't get why the example uses those files, I'm not sure if verifying against Windows store would be ok.

Comment: So essentially you want to know which certificates to use as *trusted certificates*?

Comment: Yes, that's essentially the question

Comment: Ok. But that is difficult for us to tell because the trusted certificates depend on **your very use case**. If you want to validate like Adobe Reader, you'll have to trust all the certificates on the Adobe Approved Trust List and the European Trust List plus (depending on your configuration) certificates from the OS trust store. If you want to validate in India, you most likely will want to trust Aadhaar root certificates. In a company internal application you may want to trust the root certificates of that company's PKI. Etc etc etc

Comment: Ok, that makes sense and is the answer I was looking for! If you make an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As confirmed in a comment, you most of all want to know *which certificates to use as trusted certificates*.

**This depends on your very use case.**

For example:

- If you want to validate like Adobe Reader, you'll have to trust all the certificates on the [Adobe Approved Trust List](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/approved-trust-list2.html) and the [European Union Trust Lists](https://helpx.adobe.com/document-cloud/kb/european-union-trust-lists.html) plus (depending on your configuration) certificates from the OS trust store.
- If you want to validate personal signatures in India, you most likely will want to trust Aadhaar CA certificates.
- In a company internal application you may want to trust the root certificates of that company's PKI.
- In example code of one's signature API one may want to trust a self-signed certificate one generated for using in these examples for signing (like `bruno.crt` above in example code for the iText signing API).
- Etc etc etc

Answer (score 0):

certificates parameter in method CertificateVerification.VerifyCertificates is of BouncyCastle type list, thus you will need to convert Windows Certificate Store certificates to BouncyCastle type certificates.

Below code may be useful:

```
        public void Test()
        {
            List<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate> certificates = new List<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate>();
            foreach (X509Certificate2 netCert in (new X509Store()).Certificates)
            {
                certificates.Add(Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(netCert));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the first and the second chapters of `Digital Signatures for PDF documents` (the samples which you found on the website are from this publication; it could be easily found on the Web or requested on iText's website free of charge).

There you can found how to use java's `keytool` to create certificates.

For example, for `bruno.crt` the code is as follows:

```
keytool -export -alias demo -file bruno.crt -keystore ks -storepass password
```